# Fail to rosmake

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
weiyang@ubuntu:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/robot_setup_tf$ rosmake
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] No package or stack specified.  And current directory 'robot_setup_tf' is not a package name or stack name.
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: []                                          
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/weiyang/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20131011-105536
[ rosmake ] Expanded args [] to:
[]                                             
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

It was my previously backup package before I reinstall my ubuntu which referring to the tf tutorial. Why am I not able to rosmake it right now? It suppose to be working like other package that I paste into current workspace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89656/fail-to-rosmake/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-10-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-10-10**:
How is the workspace set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package is not in your package path probably.
Try

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`
```

and rosmake again.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-10-14**:
Hi Davinci, I'm having same problem. above method didn't work. I installed using as http://nootrix.com/2012/05/ros-installation/ then i downloaded sicktoolbox. trying to rosmake without any luck. please help.

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-10-14**:
You should execute the command in the package that you are trying to build and then do rosmake after that.
Check that the package is indeed in your package path by typing echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-24**:
One best way is paste this command into your .bashrc file. It certainly helps.

**Comment by [newer92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29660/newer92/) on 2017-03-12**:
Hi,I add this line to my ~/.bashrc .It didn't work for me.I try echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.It shows:/path/to/pr2_dashboard:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks(my command is $ rosmake pr2_dashboard). any ideas?